# How do I insert html,js slider into .php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Am being faced with a worry. I have my landing page landingpage.php and wish to insert a slider...so I built a slider in html, js and wish to insert in the .php landing page, so i copy all the folders and files to the folder where i have my landing page.php but have difficulties linking my slider in correctly .

my sample codes of both .php and html,js slider below

```
<!-- TOP LANDING SECTION -->  <div style="height:93vh;width:100%;background-image: url(<?php echo base_url().'assets/frontend/flixer/images/soulafrikatv.jpg';?>)">


 <!-- logo -->
<div style="float: left;">
    <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php?home">
    <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>/assets/global/logo.png" style="margin: 18px 18px; width: 160px;" />
    </a>
</div>
<div style="float: right;margin: 18px 18px; height: 50px;" class="hidden-xs">
    <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php?home/signin" class="btn btn-warning">Sign in</a>
</div>

<!-- promo text visible for large devices -->
<div style="font-size: 85px;font-weight: bold;clear: both;padding: 200px 0px 0px 50px;color: #fff;" class="hidden-xs">
    Premium Entertainment.
    <div style="font-size: 30px; letter-spacing: .2px; color: #fff; font-weight: 400;">
        Movies, Shows, Documentaries, Series and more…
    </div>
    <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php?home/signup" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" >JOIN TODAY</a>
</div>
```

I find it difficult to insert my slider codes into the landing page

here are slider codes

```
<!-- Start WOWSlider.com HEAD section -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="engine1/style.css" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- End WOWSlider.com HEAD section -->
```

body

```
<!-- Start BODY section -->
 <div id="wowslider-container1">
  <div class="ws_images"><ul>
    <li><a href="#"><img 
 src="data1/images/home_top_banner02.jpg" alt="javascript slider" 
 title="Watch 
   Your favorite show" id="wows1_0"/></a></li>
    <li><img src="data1/images/soulafrik....jpg" alt="Soulafrikatv " 
   title="Soulafrikatv " id="wows1_1"/></li>
 </ul></div>
 <div class="ws_bullets"><div>
    <a href="#" title="Watch Your favorite show"><span><img 
   src="data1/tooltips/home_top_banner02.jpg" alt="Watch Your favorite 
  show"/>1</span></a>
    <a href="#" title="Soulafrikatv "><span><img 
src="data1/tooltips/soulafrik....jpg" alt="Soulafrikatv "/>2</span></a>
</div></div><div class="ws_script" style="position:absolute;left:-99%"><a 
href="#">slider html</a> by WOWSlider.com v8.8</div>
<div class="ws_shadow"></div>
</div>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/wowslider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/script.js"></script>
<!-- End BODY section -->
```

Comment: Did you know you can edit your question after posting? There's a link at the bottom of the question under the tags. All the relevant code should be in the question rather than in comments. It's difficult to read code in this section.

Comment: Don't Panic, thanks, edited the questions with codes...

Comment: If need be...I have a header.php  as well...do i insert the header links inside this one?

Comment: Isn't your links working correctly? What's the error you facing?

Comment: when i insert the html into my php code, the background just becomes black...no image, no slider any more